# Spectral bands of periodic differential operators

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, periodic-functions, reference-works

I am reading the book *"Multidimensional Periodic Schrödinger Operator"* (**O. Veliev**, 2015) which says on page 11:

> It is well-known the following statements about the spectral properties of $L_{t}(q)$ and $L(q)$ [two particular operators]: (...)
>
> Note that the rigorous proof of this theorem can be found in *"The Spectral Theory of Periodic Differential Equations"* (**M.S.P. Eastham**, 1973)

The theorem the author is referring to is about the band structure of the absolutely continuous spectrum of a particular periodic operator. Actually, it holds for the periodic Schrödinger operator:

$$H=-\Delta + V_{\text{per}}$$

where $V_{\text{per}}$ is a periodic potential.

My question is a bit vague, but aims to ask people knowing the book of M.S.P. Eastham mentioned above. I have access to this book from my institution but I cannot see where the proof of the mentioned theorem is. All I can see are proofs about spectral gaps (i.e. $\mathbb{R}\setminus \sigma(H)$ where $\sigma(H)$ denotes the spectrum of the operator $H$).

Are they equivalent ? I mean, is the existence of spectral gaps equivalent to a band structure of the spectrum ? I guess it is but cannot understand why all books I have seen so far consider the theorem in the "complementary" way it is proved.

I hope my question is not inappropriate for this site. If so, please close it.